# Cocoa: NSTableView DataSource doesn't set title

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nstableviewcell, nstablecolumn

I am trying to set text value of cell:

```
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    if ([[[tableColumn headerCell] stringValue] isEqualToString:@"Title"]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [[array objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"text"]);
        NSTextFieldCell *cell = [tableColumn dataCell];
        [cell setTitle:@"Cell"];
        return cell;
    }
}
```

But this doesn't works, there is no text in cell.
How can I display text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-(id)tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:` should just return the string, not the cell.

```
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    if ([[[tableColumn headerCell] stringValue] isEqualToString:@"Title"]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [[array objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"text"]);
        return @"Cell";
    }
}
```